# How to get last inserted data from DynamoDb in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, nosql

I am having table in Dynam0Db with,
**timestamp** as Partition Key,
**Status** as normal column.

I am inserting the *timestamp* and *status* in DynamoDb when ever new data comes.

I want to retrieve the last added data to the table(here we can refer timestamp).

So how can i do this(I am using lambda function with NodeJs language).

If any queries in question comment below, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream->Lambda approach suggested in previous answer is OK, however that will not work if you need to retrieve latest entry more than once. Alternatively, because you always have exactly one newest item, you can simply create another table with exactly one item with constant hash key and overwrite it every time you do update. That second table will always contain 1 record which will be your newest item. You can update that second table via stream from your main table and lambda, or directly from your application that performs original write.

[Update] As noted in the comments, using only 1 record will limit throughput to 1 partition limits (1000 WCU). If you need more, use sharding approach: on write store newest data randomly in one of N records, and on read scan all N records and pick the newest one.

Comment: Make sure to mention that this will be limited to 1000 items per second (throughput on the second table)

Comment: Why 1000? You can change throughput to any value you want

Comment: On the second table, you only have 1 item so that one item will always be in one single partition. Throughput is limited to 1000 writes per partition per second.

Comment: Right! Forgot about that. However, if that becomes a limit, you can always switch to sharding: instead of having 1 record, have N records, and assign newest item to a random id from 1 to N, then on read, read all N records and choose the latest one.

Comment: Sure, but you may want to add these details to the answer so people don't get the mislead.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a query on your table with these parameters :

```
Limit: 1,
ScanIndexForward : false
```

But it seems complicated to do the query because of the timestamp as a partition key.

The other way is to generate a stream at every new entry in your table that trigger a lambda function :
[image]

Comment: Using a stream would be the way to go. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html